# Enviar dos variables con AJAX para actualizar query

Tags: php, ajax, variables

Estoy generando una tabla por divs, unos filtros con unos selects. De momento consigo decidir cuanta cantidad de registros quiero mostrar, pero tengo que enviar más variables, por ejemplo el select que me ordenara por precio. Muestro el AJAX que tengo, haber si alguien sabe decirme como enviar mas de una variable. Gracias

```
    $(function(){
    $("#registros, #ordenar, #tipo").on("change", function(e){
      var registros ="";
      var ordenar ="";
      var tipo ="";

        if ($("#registros").val() !=null){
          registros = $("#registros").val();
        }
        if ($("#ordenar").val() !=null){
          ordenar = $("#ordenar").val();
        }
        if ($("#tipo").val() !=null){
          tipo = $("#tipo").val();
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "filtros.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
          'registros': registros,
          'ordenar': ordenar,
          'tipo': tipo
       },
            beforeSend: function(){
              $("#res").html("Procesando, espere por favor...")
            },
            success: function (resultado){
              $("#res").html(resultado);
            }
    });
});

    });
```

Luego en el otro archivo que genera la consulta esta así.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT productos.id, productos.producto, 
productos.imagen, productos.alias, posibles.idproducto, posibles.tipo, 
posibles.entrada, posibles.mensualidad, posibles.final, posibles.total 
FROM productos, posibles WHERE productos.id = posibles.idproducto AND 
posibles.tipo =" . $_POST["tipo"]. " ORDER BY posibles.final $orden 
$limit");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no me equivoco lo que buscas es enviar más de una variable en el AJAX, para ello solo tienes que añadir dichas variables al JSON que envías, al `data`

```
data: {
    "registros": $("#registros").val(),
    "Dato": "Dato",
    "Otro_Dato": "otro_dato"
}
```

Sería tal cual tienes el de registros pero con los nuevos datos a enviar y añadiendo el id de precios para que la función se ejecutara también cuando su `select` cambie, por ejemplo con el precio tu código quedaría algo así:

```
$(function(){
    $("#registros, #precio").on("change", function(e){
       $.ajax({
           url: "filtros.php",
           type: "post",
           dataType: "html",
           data: {
              'registros': $("#registros").val(),
              'precio': $("#precio").val()
           },
           beforeSend: function(){
             $("#res").html("Procesando, espere por favor...")
           },
           success: function (resultado){
             $("#res").html(resultado);
           }
       });
   });
});
```

Asegúrate de que siempre estén separados por comas menos el último dato que introduzcas.

Tendrías que tener en cuenta el valor que tenga por defecto el selector. Si `$("#precio").val()` de primeras es `null` podría darte problemas. Asegúrate de añadirle un valor a la opción inicial para que no pase.

Otra forma de evitar este problema sería pasando variables inicializadas en el `data` en vez de el valor puro. Es decir:

```
$("#registros, #precio").on("change", function(e){
    var registros = "";
    var precio = "";

    if ($("#registros").val() != null) {
        registros = $("#registros").val();
    } 

    if ($("#precio").val() != null) {
        precio = $("#precio").val();
    }

    /* AJAX */
}
```

Y en el data pasarle esas variables en vez del dato como tal:

```
data: {
    "registros": registros,
    "precio": precio
}
```

De esta forma las variables nunca serán nulas y el código lo leerá bien.

**Como dato extra:** 
Al tener el Ajax en un `onchange` no necesitas meterlo en otra función. Obviamente desconozco si hay más código o algún motivo para ello pero, tal cual está el código ahora no haría falta la primera y última línea, el `onchange` ya está creando una función en sí.

Comment: Lo que necesito es que tengo dos "selects" uno es #registros y otro #ordenar. Cuando cambien su estado tienen que cambiar la consulta SQL, he realizado la prueba que me dices, pero claro no le llega la info de #ordenar. Gracias

Comment: Pero ¿tienen que cambiar el estado los dos para que se envíe o con que lo cambie uno basta? Quiero decir, ¿se podría ejecutar si solo cambia `registros`?

Comment: Exacto! con que cambie uno es suficiente, pero claro hay que tener en cuenta que si eligen que quieren mostrar dos resultados y luego el de menor precio se tienen que mantener las dos variables activas.

Comment: En ese caso bastaría con indicarle que la función se ejecute cuando cambia cualquiera de los dos `$("#registros, #ordenar").on("change", function(e){` , ahora edito la respuesta para ponerlo mejor y explicarlo más

Comment: Es estupendo!!!! muchas gracias a funcionado a la perfección! Sabrias como pasarle tambien en la ID de registro que estoy? no se si puedo hacer la pregunta en el mismo post? Millones de gracias Rabegi

Comment: ¿Por "id de registro que estoy" te refieres al valor del selector? Creo que sería conveniente que hicieras una nueva pregunta con eso explicado (Sinceramente desconozco si editar la pregunta principal y añadirlo estaría bien, aun soy nueva también en SO y las cosas así se me escapan)

Comment: Perfecto, ya genero otra pregunta si no consigo solucionarlo, gracias!!

Comment: Lo puse como me pusiste ahora y no me funciona, no se que estoy haciendo mal, hay alguna forma de pegarte el código de nuevo?

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta con el código para que lo veamos

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta gracias!

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en la consulta, porque hasta que no cambio el select de $tipo el resto me devuelve error. ¿Que puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

Dento del tag `data` separalos por comas

```
data: {'registros': $("#registros").val() , 'valor2': valor2}
```